# Why does textures work with the default cube, but not with any new cube I add?

Tags: texturing, materials, uv

I am following the "noob to pro" wiki tutorial, and in the basic texturing part, when I apply a material and a texture to the default cube, everything works fine.

If, however, I add a new cube and create a new material and texture here, the result is all broken up and odd-looking. It seems as if it's treating my cube's faces as a pair of triangles instead of just the square face of a cube.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You need to unwrap the new cube.

Comment: @ARadish Is the default cube unwrapped by default?

Comment: Uhhhh... no... but his settings may cause the other cube to be triangulated or somink like that, whereas the default cube is always the same.

Comment: Okay, unwrap it, I will look into that. Thank you! But why are the settings for the default cube different than the new cube I add? And how do I change that? Would I even want to?

Comment: Ok, so I read up on unwrapping and tried doing that, but it still doesn't work. The triangle thing isn't happening anymore, but instead it seems like it's trying to stretch the texture over the surface of the entire cube instead of applying it to each side. I'm probably missing something obvious here, but what?

Comment: Unwrapping isn't usually a nice automatic process. You'd need to go into edit mode, select your object, open up a second panel in blender (like split your 3D view in half), and change one of the views to the UV image editor.  There you'll actually be able to see how blender is applying your texture to the cube and manipulate it to your liking.

Comment: I see. That sounds like a rather complicated process given my very early stage of trying to learn Blender, and the wiki gives the impression that making simple textures is a lot easier than this (not even mentioning unwrapping at this point). Is unwrapping the only way to solve this, or is there an easier way that will not require me to go through this whole process?

Comment: Could you please describe the steps you use to create the second cube?  Also, what renderer are you using?  Blender Internal or Cycles?

Answer (score 3):

Okay, here's how we unwrap a cube so that we don't get any whonky image output when we view the image mapped onto it.

### *Option A*

[image]

Go into edit mode, select the entire mesh, and then hit <kbd>U</kbd> > Cube projection. This is what to do if you want the same texture on every face, which is what I assume you are going for. *However!* if this is not wht you are going for, there is always ...

### *Option B*

So who here has seen a baseball? *Raises hand* "me!..Me!"
You know how those two white panels are stitched together interlockish-ly? how if you were to cut the red seams they'd *Pop* out and you could lay them flat? That is what we do when we unwrap things, but we still need seams.

If your cube were made out of paper, and you folded it to get it into a cube shape, what did the paper look like before it was folded?

Like this maybe?

[image]

Well, what you need to do, is select all the edges that need to be seams and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> +  <kbd>E</kbd> > Mark Seam. this will make them BRIGHT RED!!!!
It also means that those edges are now like the seams on a baseball, and all you have to do is <kbd>U</kbd> > Unwrap.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Sincerely I don't quite understand what is your problem. Some screenshots would greatly help to understand what you ment. But. If your result is something like this:

[image: result]

Then you have a new cube in the same position as the old one. Just select it and press G to grab and move it to a new place. You don't really need to unwrap it if your texture is procedural like "Clouds" from tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

Just to add to @A Radish's answer.
You can also unwrap a cube in a T shape without seams by unwrapping and using **follow active quads**.

In edit mode first select a face then select the rest of the faces with **<kbd>A</kbd>**. Then just press <kbd>U</kbd> and select follow active quads.

[image]