# Problem: material has stretched on side of shape

Tags: materials, uv, modifiers

I have a cube that I have cut into triangles with a boolean modifier. I have animated this shape to open out in various ways and begun adding images/ materials onto the sides of this shape.

Some materials have stretched, usually I would double check the material is assigned correctly and made sure I have done UV unwrap.

[image]

This screenshot shows what is seen when rendered and what it's meant to look like. All of those pieces of the shape should be correct but two aren't on this side, and are incorrect on a few others as well.

Is there anyway I can rectify this or is there someway someone can take a look?

Comment: A proper unwrapping job should suffice.

Comment: what does that mean?

Comment: Like i've said I've already unwrapped, if you could elaborate on a "proper unwrapping job" that would be more helpful

Comment: To Easily UV unwrap a cube use follow active quads: http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/27351/1853

Comment: you dont have to use triangles for the UV map if you just want the mesh to have these triangle shapes for an animation. just use a default unwrap with seams at its edges.

Answer (score 2):

1. Only select all the faces on that side of the cube.
2. Press <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>NumPad 7</kbd> to [align the view to the faces](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/15046/2217) (if you have not rotated the cube simply switching to one of the [main views](http://www.blender.org/manual/editors/3dview/navigate/3d_view.html#rotating-the-view) will work.).
3. Press <kbd>U</kbd> > *Project from View (Bounds)*

Answer (score 1):

I decided to explore a bit and found that while having the vertices selected, select Mesh > vertices > delete doubles worked for me.

The other examples I found hadn't worked in my case but thank you for the suggestions.