# set the UVs to their vertices's coordinates?

Tags: uv

Is there a way to unwrap the UV's so that they match the coordinates of their respective vertices in the XY, XZ and YZ plane?

I have a tiling texture and all my faces are aligned to either the XY, XZ or YZ plane. So, I basically want the texture tiles each unit in either direction.

Comment: It is extremely unclear what you are asking. A UV map is what defines the position (coordinates) of the vertices of your mesh on the texture.

Comment: you want the UVmap to look like the mesh ?

Comment: Use `U` *> Project From View* if that is what you want.

Comment: Basically, I have a tiling texture and all my faces are aligned to either the XY, XZ or YZ plane. So, I basically want that the texture tiles each unit in either direction.

Comment: THere are already several Q&A posted on here about UV unwrapping

Comment: @NoviceInDisguise thanks, I'm dumb to not think of that

Comment: Try the active quads type

Comment: @NoviceInDisguise yup, that's even easier, thanks again

Comment: Go ahead and edit your question to make it clearer what you were asking

Comment: @NoviceInDisguise done, I hope it's clearer now

Comment: I think this is a duplicate of this question, but it is clearer now. http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/27315/why-does-textures-work-with-the-default-cube-but-not-with-any-new-cube-i-add/27351#27351

Answer (score 2):

To get your image to display once on each face, select the entire mesh and press <kbd>U</kbd> > *Reset*. Each face will now be mapped to the image bounds.

In the *UV/Image Editor* header turn on *UV and Edit mode selection sync*.
[image: UV and Edit mode selection sync]
Now in the 3D view you can select any faces with the texture on the wrong way, and rotate them in the UV Editor.

[image: animated gif]