# Texturing the sides of a cube (without UV mapping) only appearing correctly in Rendered View?

Tags: mesh, materials

I'm working on a Minecraft themed map, and have a ton cubes. Some cubes require 3 materials (a top texture, bottom texture, and sides texture). When I apply the top and bottom materials, it applies it correctly. However, when I apply the side material, it looks distorted and smeared, and only appears correctly when viewing it from the Renderer Viewport (rather than the Material Viewport).

Material View:

[image]

Rendered View:

[image]

Is there a way to fix it, without resorting to UV mapping?

Comment: Is scale applied? If it is, then the only thing I can think to do is to UV Unwrap, but instead of taking the time to do it manually, and creating seams, you can just project from cube.

Comment: @J.A.Streich It's already set to cube projection. That's what makes it work in rendered view, but it's not appearing correctly in material view.

Comment: Why are you avoiding UVs? That will give you total control on the texture mapping. Unwrapping a cube takes 2 minutes to learn: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=e_dTES_CCbY another way to do it is http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/27351/1853

Comment: @cegaton Overkill, and overhead; I don't need that much control, and with several thousand of these cubes being on the map, I'm worried about performance implications. Infact, with the manner in which I merge cubes (to remove hidden faces and duplicate verticies), UV mapping is likely far more difficult than you're imagining.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not optimistic that there is a way to "solve" this without using UV maps.

If it is any encouragement, understand that many people before you have converted minecraft data into 3D data sets:  http://www.purplefrog.com/~thoth/minecraft-webgl/two.html ; and they used UVs.

I can't remember why I wrote [this](http://web.purplefrog.com/~thoth/blender/python-cookbook/uv-from-geometry-cubic.html), but it is python code that makes up a UV map based on the position of the vertices relative to whichever of the XY, YZ, or XZ planes they are most aligned with.

Here's a copy inline:

```
import bpy
import bmesh
from math import *
from mathutils import *

def set_uvs_for_face(bm, fi, uv_layer):
    face = bm.faces[fi]
    normal = face.normal
    dx=abs(normal[0])
    dy=abs(normal[1])
    dz=abs(normal[2])

    if (dz > dx):
        u = Vector([1,0,0])
        if (dz>dy):
            v = Vector([0,1,0])
        else:
            v = Vector([0,0,1])
    else:
        v = Vector([0,0,1])
        if dx>dy:
            u = Vector([0,1,0])
        else:
            u = Vector([1,0,0])
    for i in range(len(face.loops)):
        l = face.loops[i]
        l[uv_layer].uv = [ u.dot(l.vert.co),
                           v.dot(l.vert.co)]

def set_uvs(mesh, name=None):

    if name is None:
        if 0<len(mesh.uv_textures):
            uv = mesh.uv_textures[0]
        else:
            uv = mesh.uv_textures.new("cubic")
    else:
        uv = mesh.uv_textures.get(name)
        if uv is None:
            uv = mesh.uv_textures.new(name)

    bm = bmesh.new()
    bm.from_mesh(mesh)

    uv_layer = bm.loops.layers.uv[uv.name]

    for fi in range(len(bm.faces)):
        set_uvs_for_face(bm, fi, uv_layer)

    bm.to_mesh(mesh)

#
#
#

mode = bpy.context.mode
if 'OBJECT' != mode:
    bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='OBJECT')

obj = bpy.context.active_object
set_uvs(obj.data)

if 'OBJECT' != mode:
    bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode = mode)
```